# Msg 4145, Level 15, State 1, Line 1 An expression of non-boolean type specified in a context where a condition is expected

Tags: sql-server

Please correct my query why I am getting this error,

```
select 
    a.productid, b.gender
from 
    tblperson a 
join
    tblgender b on (select productid from tblpurchase)
```

Why I am getting this error?

> Msg 4145, Level 15, State 1, Line 1
>   An expression of non-boolean type specified in a context where a condition is expected

Comment: Query makes no sense.  Try asking another question with sample data, desired results, and an explanation of what you want to do.

Comment: You are getting that error because your join condition makes no sense.  You join two tables by specifying the columns that link the two (something like `on a.genderID = b.genderID`).

Comment: please correct me, can't we use select clause inside the 'on' condition?

Comment: There is no prohibition on using `SELECT` inside an `ON` clause. But not like that. It has to evaluate as a boolean. And almost certainly you won't need to do it here. You need to explain what you are trying to do, not just post broken code.

Comment: Thank you Martin, now I got the logic here but unclear how to use select clause inside ON clause. Can you give one example?

Comment: Well an example where it would be syntactically valid would be `select * from a join b ON EXISTS(SELECT a.x INTERSECT SELECT b.x)` but this is unlikely to be what you need.

Answer (score 1):

I can't correct it, because it's not clear what you are trying to do, but you are getting the error because of this line:

```
on (select productid from tblpurchase)
```

Joining on a lone subquery is not valid syntax.

You have to JOIN on a condition like:

```
on a.Column1 = b.Column1
```